# Is there a built-in function to join a set of strings?

Tags: join, jsf-2, jstl, el, omnifaces

I've a model that contains a `java.util.Set<String>` I'd like to join in my facelet, but since `fn:join` only accepts `String[]` I neither can't pass it directly to it nor use `elements.toArray()`.

I'm not aware of another function that joins non-arrays into a single String. What I'm doing right now is

```
<ui:repeat value="#{elements.tags.toArray()}" var="tag" varStatus="st">
  #{tag} #{not st.last ? ', ' : ''}
</ui:repeat>
```

Which is way too complicated for such a simple task. Am I missing something (maybe a utility library?) or do I need to deploy my own joiner method?

Comment: Do you have OmniFaces at hands? It has one.

Comment: Yes, no deployment without it. Maybe it's the hour here, but I'm unable to find the method. Can you put that as an answer?

Comment: `#{of:joinCollection(setOfStrings, ', ')}` http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters

Comment: Darn, wouldn't have expected it under *Converters*. Alas, it's a transformation, so that's okay. Thanks!

Comment: Categorizing them is indeed a pain :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`of:joinCollection()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/of/joinCollection.fn.html) for the job (see [VDL documentation](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/) for a better overview of all `of:xxx` functions).

```
#{of:joinCollection(elements.tags, ', ')}
```

#### See also:

- https://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters